# Multiple certificates in TLS handshake "certificate" message

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

My task is to parse server name from HTTPS messages . I have been asked to parse it from "client hello" extensions and also from "certicate", "commonname" field .

There are multiple certificates in "certificate" message . For example when open google with https and listen this via wireshark I see 2 certificates first has commonname "*.google.com" and the second has commonname "Google internet authority" .  First one is the server name that I connected the second one is authority who signed the certificate .

My question can I be sure that server name(google.com in my case) will be in first certificate message always . Do I need to care the other certificates in a certificate message if I want to get servername only .

Comment: The order can differ so you need to get all certificates and find, which of them is the end-entity one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, rfc 2246, 4346 and 5246 (respectively TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2) all state that the server certificate should be the first one :

> "This is a sequence (chain) of X.509v3 certificates. The sender's
>    certificate must come first in the list. Each following
>    certificate must directly certify the one preceding it."

It was also clear in SSL 3.0 :

> " certificate_list:  This is a sequence (chain) of X.509.v3
>   certificates, ordered with the sender's certificate first followed
>   by any certificate authority certificates proceeding sequentially
>   upward."

But in the real world, there is a lot of misconfigured servers sending certificates in whatever order, so you will have to reorder them, sorry.

Comment: Exactly that was confusing me "The sender's certificate must come first in the list". Do you have advice for a pattern to reorder them.

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir, look for the Issuer DN and Subject DN in each certificate: the Subject DN of the following certificate that certifies the one preceding it should be the Issuer DN of that preceding certificate.